# Calculating ridge regression solution by hand (matrix form) [r]

Tags: r, regression, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate ridge regression and OLS regression by hand, both models have solution in analytic form. I always think it is nice to calculate everything by hand and then start using function.

While I am able to calcule OLS regression by hand (coeff are same as using `lm` function) I am having issues with ridge regression.

I would like to ask where am I making mistake

```
library(glmnet)
library(tidyverse)

y = mtcars$hp %>% as.matrix()
X = model.matrix(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec + wt, mtcars) %>% as.matrix()


# OLS model
solve(t(X) %*% X) %*%t(X) %*%y
lm(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec + wt, mtcars) %>% coef()


# Ridge regression
glmnet(X, y, lambda = 30) %>% 
  broom::tidy()

solve(t(X) %*% X + 30*diag(5)) %*%t(X) %*%y
```